# How to access the state of a component at a superior level without using useContext?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface

let me explain my question.
I would like to create expanding flex cards, here is the exemple on codepen : https://codepen.io/z-/pen/OBPJKK

and here is my code for each button :
basically I have a component which is called HomeButtons that generates every flex cards. Inside this component I have a smaller component called readMore. In this component I have a useState that allows me to toggle individually each button to add or retreive an active class. If the active class is present, that means that the selected button must expand and the other ones must shrink.

What I would like to do is to access the readMore state ouside of the readMore subcomponent. That way I could write a function to remove the active class from a card if the user clicks on another card like so :

```
function setToUnactive() {
if (readMore(true)) {
readMore(false)}
}
```

My question is how can I get the state of readMore outside of the readMore subcomponent ? Do I need to use useContext ? Because that seems very simple to do but I tried a lot of things and nothing works. Can I pass the state readMore as a prop of the component ReadMore ? Thank you !

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../style/catalogue.scss';
import collectionsItems from '../Components/collectionsItemsData';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


const HomeButtons = ({}) => {

    function ReadMore() {
        const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false)
        function toggleSetReadMore() {
            setReadMore(!readMore)
        }
        return (
            <p className='showmore' onClick={toggleSetReadMore} className={readMore ? "collection-item active" : "collection-item"}>TOGGLE BUTTON</p>
        )
    }

    return <div>
        {collectionsItems.map((collectionItem) => {
            const { id, category, img } = collectionItem;
            return < article key={id} >
                <img className="item-img" src={img} alt=''/>
                <ReadMore />
                <Link to={`/${category}`} className="item-title">{category}</Link>
            </article>
        })}
    </div>
}

export default HomeButtons;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need extract ReadMore component from function outside!
And for your problem you can lift state up(https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). And since at the same time only one item can be opened you can do something like this:

```
function ReadMore({ isOpened, setOpened }) {
  return (
    <p
      onClick={setOpened}
      className={isOpened ? "collection-item active" : "collection-item"}
    >
      TOGGLE BUTTON
    </p>
  );
}

const HomeButtons = () => {
  const [openedItemId, setOpenedItemId] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      {collectionsItems.map((collectionItem) => {
        const { id, category, img } = collectionItem;
        return (
          <article key={id}>
            <img className="item-img" src={img} alt="" />
            <ReadMore
              isOpened={openedItemId === id}
              setOpened={() => setOpenedItemId(id)}
            />
            <Link to={`/${category}`} className="item-title">
              {category}
            </Link>
          </article>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: wow that's perfect thank you so much !!!